# Redirección JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo una redirección a distintas *URL*s según la opción seleccionada en un `select`.
Cada opción es una distinta *URL* y tiene que redirigir con solo tocar la opción seleccionada.

En el select he puesto el parámetro de cada opción.

Por el momento lo estoy manejando así, pero no me redirecciona

```
$("#redirectGym").change(function() {
    var url = "https://gym-tek.com/clientes/loginCliente.xhtml?idOpcion=";
    var urlGym = $('#redirectGym').find(":selected").val();
    window.open(url + urlGym, '_blank');
});
```

```
<select name="redirectGym" onchange="redirectGym()">
    <option value="0" selected>-Selecciona una opción-</option>
    <option value="c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b">Opcion 1</option>
    <option value="a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c">Opcion 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tiene es que añadir el atributo `id` a tu select ya que lo estás seleccionando con el selector de `id`(`#redirectGym`) y quitar el evento `onchange` porque lo estas añadiendo con jQuery con el método `change`.

También puedes cambiar el selector y no añadir el atributo `id`.

```
$("select[name='redirectGym']").change();
```

```js
$("#redirectGym").change(function() {
  var url = "https://gym-tek.com/clientes/loginCliente.xhtml?idOpcion=";
  var urlGym = $('#redirectGym').find(":selected").val();
  console.log(url + urlGym);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="redirectGym" name="redirectGym">
  <option value="0" selected>-Selecciona una opción-</option>
  <option value="c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b">Opcion 1</option>
  <option value="a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c">Opcion 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Gracias, me ayudó mucho. Ya lo solventé